# не могу передать в функцию нужный индекс для элемента, мне нужно чтоб класс задавался только для выбраного элемента

Tags: javascript, angular

```
<div class="item-row" *ngFor="let item of portfolio; let i = index">
  <div class="row-box">
    <div class="items-box" [ngClass]="{'description-close': hideDesc, 'description-open': showDesc}">
      <h2 class="title-portfolio">{{item.title}}</h2>
      <div class="desc-portfolio">{{item.description}}</div>
    </div>
    <span class="read-more" (click)="changeClass(i)">read more...</span>
  </div>
</div>
    public showDesc: boolean = false; 
public hideDesc: boolean = true; 
changeClass(i) 
{ 
if(this.showDesc === false && this.hideDesc === true){ 

this.showDesc = true; 
this.hideDesc = false }
else{
 this.showDesc = false;
 this.hideDesc = true }
 }
```

Comment: в какую функцию? например в `changeClass` вполне передается индекс элемента

Comment: public showDesc: boolean = false;
  public hideDesc: boolean = true;
  changeClass() {
    if(this.showDesc === false && this.hideDesc === true){
      debugger
      this.showDesc = true;
      this.hideDesc = false
    }else {
      this.showDesc = false;
      this.hideDesc = true
    }
  }

Comment: это в файле ts. Это простой переключатель класса на true/false(делаю read more)

Comment: debugger показал что передаю 1

Comment: где у тебя параметр в объявлении функции changeClass?

Comment: он там бил я просто удялил то что наделал, оставил только рабочий переключатель. А так то  в файле ts писал changeClass(i)...ну и пробовал как то реализовать этот индекс

Comment: там если пользователь тикает на один read more то откроются все, еще раз тикнет и они все закроются. А нужно что б один

Comment: а у меня конструктор подсвечивается красным constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

Comment: блин но оно работаает!!! дело в том что у меня там уже есть один конструктор в файле ts. Веб шторм написал //ts-ignore и ваш construktor перестал ругаться теперь мой конструктор красний нове равно все работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется вы все усложнили, было бы проще просто делать `toggle` этого класса:

```
<div class="item-row" *ngFor="let item of portfolio">
    <div class="row-box">
        <div class="items-box" #box>
            <h2 class="title-portfolio">{{ item.title }}</h2>
            <div class="desc-portfolio">{{ item.description }}</div>
        </div>
        <span class="read-more" (click)="changeClass(box)">read more...</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Компонент:

```
private descriptionOpenedClass = 'description-open';

private descriptionClosedClass = 'description-close';

constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

public changeClass(box: HTMLDivElement): void {
    const descriptionOpened = box.classList.contains(this.descriptionOpenedClass);

    if (descriptionOpened) {
        this.renderer.removeClass(box, this.descriptionOpenedClass);
        this.renderer.addClass(box, this.descriptionClosedClass);
    } else {
        this.renderer.removeClass(box, this.descriptionClosedClass);
        this.renderer.addClass(box, this.descriptionOpenedClass);
    }
}
```

**UPD**:

Либо же мутировать объект из массива `portfolio`, добавляя ему новое свойство:

```
<div class="item-row" *ngFor="let item of portfolio">
    <div class="row-box">
        <div class="items-box" [ngClass]="{
            'description-open': item.descriptionOpened,
            'description-close': !item.descriptionOpened
        }">
            <h2 class="title-portfolio">{{ item.title }}</h2>
            <div class="desc-portfolio">{{ item.description }}</div>
        </div>
        <span class="read-more" (click)="changeClass(item)">read more...</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Компонент:

```
public changeClass(item: any): void {
    // изначально свойство `descriptionOpened` не существует
    // поэтому `!undefined => true`
    item.descriptionOpened = !item.descriptionOpened;
}
```

Comment: ану  я попробую не уходите

Comment: я сделал импорт но оно все равно красное. Консолька говорит '$pageLeaveStream'

Comment: что красное не могу понять? :) консоль такого не может говорить)

Comment: а тут фото можно кинуть? както ))

Comment: а можно еще вопрос, вы сделали чтоб текс сразу бил открит при загрузке а он должен быть закрытим. просто сижу розбираюсь в вашем коде

Comment: ищу вас..в телеграме